# F# SQL type provider - why aren't all stored procedures provided?

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#, type-providers

I'm trying to access an existing database via the Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.SqlDataConnection type. There are some stored procedures that are not provided (but most are).

I'm trying to determine what differentiates the unprovidable procedures from the others -- I believe that custom types are one reason the type-provision might fail, but they don't appear to be present here.

For what other reasons might our stored procedures be unprovidable?

Edit:

I've identified the following block as one that causes unprovidability:

```
      EXEC @intReturn = te_audit_log @action = 'I',
                                     @user_id = @intUserId,
                                     @table_id = 1,
                                     @audit_action = 'A',
                                     @data_id = @intStatus,
                                     @session_guid = @session_guid,
                                     @effective_date = @actual_timedate,
                                     @employee_id = @employee_id
```

...I think it is because the sproc that is being "exec"ed also having paths that return values from a temp table.

Comment: Just guessing: maybe those SPs that have output parameters are not provided.

Comment: The one I'm looking at now, in one of its branches, does a SELECT from a #temp table it creates. When I remove this, F# is able to provide the sproc.

Comment: It may be because it cannot execute [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx) or sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set and return metadata. I've observed this when SP contain temp table. From documentation "sp_describe_first_result_set returns an error in any of the following cases. -If the statement uses a temporary table."

Comment: Try if for stored procedures which are not provided you can get correct metadata using this SP. I bet that they are the same which cause error. Reasons why are in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx) section remarks.

Comment: Founded in source code [FMONTY](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/blob/2753a097f224015c76f01346311c453a43240649/src/SqlClient.Tests/SqlCommand.fsx) `//Fallback to metadata retrieval through FMTONLY
type UseFMTONLY = SqlCommandProvider<"exec dbo.[Init]", connectionString>
let useFMTONLY = new UseFMTONLY()
useFMTONLY.Execute()` and here [SET FMTONLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx) which was replaced by procedures which I described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that type provider cannot get stored procedures(or other db object), because type provider cannot get metadata about result set. Check [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx) 
and [SET FMTONLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx)

Reasons are specified in documenation in remark section:

> sp_describe_first_result_set returns an error in any of the following cases.
>
> If the input @tsql is not a valid Transact-SQL batch. Validity is determined by parsing and analyzing the Transact-SQL batch. Any errors caused by the batch during query optimization or during execution are not considered when determining whether the Transact-SQL batch is valid.
>
> If @params is not NULL and contains a string that is not a syntactically valid declaration string for parameters, or if it contains a string that declares any parameter more than one time.
>
> If the input Transact-SQL batch declares a local variable of the same name as a parameter declared in @params.
>
> If the statement uses a **temporary table**.
>
> The query includes the creation of a permanent table that is then queried.
>
> When multiple possible first statements are found in a batch, their results can differ in number of columns, column name, nullability, and data type. How these differences are handled is described in more detail here:
>
> If the number of columns differs, an error is thrown and no result is returned.
>
> If the column name differs, the column name returned is set to NULL.
>
> It the nullability differs, the nullability returned will allow NULLs.
>
> If the data type differs, an error will be thrown and no result is returned except for the following cases:
>
> - varchar(a) to varchar(a') where a' > a.
> - varchar(a) to varchar(max)
> - nvarchar(a) to nvarchar(a') where a' > a.
> - nvarchar(a) to nvarchar(max)
> - varbinary(a) to varbinary(a') where a' > a.
> - varbinary(a) to varbinary(max)

DB objects and queries that contain above cases are simply not present.

Checking if TSQL Stored Procedure return correct metadata

`SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set ('[schema].[name]',<params> , 0)` ;