# LINQ - return type could not be detected

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a simple stored procedure that is returning a value.  However when dropping that SP in LINQ dbml I get:

> The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected.  Set the return type for each stored procedure in the Properties Window.

I have a few SPs that show this, but the majority come through fine.  I don't want to have to set them manually if I don't absolutely have to - I want the SP to be correct and easy for LINQ to determine.

Here is the SP:

```
@intPD integer

AS

set nocount on

Declare
@dtmStart datetime, @dtmEnd datetime, @fltDown float

EXEC sp_ShiftStart @intPD, @dtmStart OUTPUT

Declare @results TABLE(Dur varchar(100))

Insert into @results
    EXEC sp_Down 3, @intPD, @dtmStart, @dtmEnd, null, 10, @fltDown OUTPUT

Select @fltDown as Dur
```

The return is a single row with a single field called 'Dur'

But LINQ doesn't seem to understand even though I have specifically defined the output.

Comment: Probably you need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32128830/5070879 Short answer in some condition described there you cannot fetch metadata needed for creating mapping/provider/so on...

Comment: I looked over that one, but I am using SQL Server 2008, not 2012 (so I don't have that sp for checks).

Comment: But you have `SET FMTONLY`;

Comment: When I set that in the SP (to ON), it gives me no results. By default it is set to OFF, which gives me results.  I can't imaging setting it so that I get no results, though.

Comment: You don't understand it's purpose. Setting it on will bring you back only metadata of SP of resultset (columns, types and so on)

Comment: What I mean is: if you cannot determine metadata about resultset then code which use it cannot do it automatically. Try SET FMTONLY with procedure which works for you.

Comment: Try this: `SET FMTONLY ON;
GO
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Name
GO
SET FMTONLY OFF;` and see what this option is for.

Comment: I must just not know what I am doing.  I put that into a query window with my own table and it just shows fields only (column headers with no data), nothing else.  when I remove it, then I get the rows.