# How can I get base table names with FMTONLY

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a tool that gets metadata about stored procedures by doing this:

```
SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON; 
SET FMTONLY ON;
EXEC {ProcName} {ProcParams}
```

passing a proc name and dummy (null) params.

I load this into a data table and call `GetSchemaTable` to determine the resulting column names and datatypes. This works very well.

But I've noticed that there isn't any way to tell what database **table** is the source of each column, and I need this for my application as well. Is there a way to do this?

(I'm also not attached to getting the metadata in this way, so I'm open to suggestions that do this a different way entirely.)

Comment: you should be able to get the source SQL in the meta data -- then just parse that for table and field names

Comment: There is no way to do this, furthermore a column is not necessarily derived from a single table, or any table at all for that matter. Consider the column `TableA.Value / TableB.Total AS PercentColumn` - What would the source table for this column be? Or you could have a number of tables in a `UNION`, so you might have multiple tables in this scenario too. You may need to address why you need to know the source table for each column, and find a solution to this issue.

Comment: @Hogan: wouldn't that mean the pretty big job of writing a full T-SQL parser?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank - It would for the general solution.  It might not for the specific solution.  It totally depends on the content of his stored procedures.  for example if every stored procedure had a comment like this: `-- Source Tables: TabA, TabB, TabC`  Then it would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx) to get all metadata about result set. Works with **SQL Server 2012+**.

**[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/81790d/6/0)**

```
DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
  N'select a.PartId , a.PartName , b.GroupName 
from Parts as a inner join Groups as b 
on a.GroupRef = b.GroupId';

SELECT name AS [Columns]
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@tsql, NULL, 1)
```

Same applies to:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'EXEC dbo.procedure_name', NULL, 1);
```

Keep in mind there are limitations, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32128830/5070879).