# Get the first result set for the stored procedure which has temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building report writer which I need to select the data source, fields, filters and then preview. Data sources are nothing but the stored procedures or views. Fields are the result set columns. I am able to get the first result set object for stored procedures which includes simple select that too without executing the stored procedure.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object (OBJECT_ID('SP_Name'), NULL) 
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

However, I do not get the first result set for stored procedures which are using a temporary table or have select *. Is there a way to get the metadata for a stored procedure without executing it?

Comment: Probably not. This is limitation of describe_first_result_set [SQL type provider - why aren't all stored procedures provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678958/f-sql-type-provider-why-arent-all-stored-procedures-provided)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Thank you for your answer. Apart from using the describe_first_result_set, can we use something else to get the metadata without executing the stored procedure that you know of?